# Exporting datagridview to csv file adding some data to it

Tags: c#

I am trying to export data from datagridview to csv  from mysql. I want to some additional information to every row .

mysql query:
**select vehicleregistration from wlist**

my csv output :

**YV07WMU**

I need the output like

**YV07WMU; GBR; 20/08/2014;** -- here I need to add GBR; and today's date; at the end of each row.

this is my code: I don't where I am going wrong.

```
MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand();
            myCommand.Connection = conn;


            myCommand.CommandText = "select VehicleRegistration from blacklist";
            //myCommand.Connection = myConn;
            DataTable data = new DataTable();
            MySqlDataAdapter myAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(myCommand);
            //myAdapter.SelectCommand = myCommand;
            myAdapter.Fill(data);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = data;
            this.dataGridView1.Refresh();

            if (dataGridView1.RowCount > 0)
            {
                string value = "";
                DataGridViewRow dr = new DataGridViewRow();
                StreamWriter swOut = new StreamWriter("C:/a/blist.csv");

                //write header rows to csv
                for (int i = 0; i <= dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    if (i > 0)
                    {
                        //  swOut.Write(",");
                    }
                    // swOut.Write(dataGridView1.Columns[i].HeaderText);
                }

                swOut.WriteLine();

                //write DataGridView rows to csv
                for (int j = 0; j <= dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; j++)
                {
                    if (j > 0)
                    {
                        swOut.WriteLine(" ");
                    }

                    dr = dataGridView1.Rows[j];

                    for (int i = 0; i <= dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1; i++)
                    {
                        if (i > 0)
                        {
                            swOut.WriteLine(",");
                        }

                        value = dr.Cells[i].Value.ToString();
                        //replace comma's with spaces
                        value = value.Replace(',', ' ');
                        //replace embedded newlines with spaces
                        value = value.Replace(Environment.NewLine, " ");

                        swOut.Write(value);
                    }
                }
                swOut.Close();
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you looping through the gridview and not the datatable?

Comment: I don't know, it just seems that if you had to loop through the datatable you could have half as much code...